# jQuery - Change text and link based on anchor visability

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a breadcrumb's text and link that needs to be updated when an anchor on this very long page is reached.

Example:

```
<div class="crumbs hidden-xs">
<a href="#">Parent link</a>   /   <a href="#summary" class="link-location">Summary</a>
</div>
```

Example of anchor far down on the page:

```
<h1 id="chapter-2" class="page-location">Chapter 2 title here</h1>
```

When the above anchor is at the top of the screen, I need:

```
<a href="#summary" class="link-location">Summary</a>
```

to change to:

```
<a href="#chapter-2" class="link-location">Chapter 2 title here</a>
```

and when I am all the way back at the top of the page there should be no breadcrumb:

```
<div class="crumbs hidden-xs">
<a href="#">Parent link</a>
</div>
```

I have tried a number of things and I'm a bit puzzled. This lead to me getting the menu to work:

```
$("#main-nav .panel a").on("click", function() {
$('.link-location').html( $(this).html() );
});`
```

I have also tried the following:

```
var t = $(".page-location").offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
        $('.link-location').html( $(this).html() );
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to do anything for me.

You can find an example of my layout here: http://jsfiddle.net/15298c0p/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `any thoughts` is not a real question here. try something and when it doesn't work the way you want come back with your code and ask for help then

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought that "I have tried everything I could find" was a given. I have edited my problem if it matters.

Comment: @charlietfl Any thoughts? ;)

Comment: getting better at showing code, that's important here as it shows effort and is better to learn based on mistakes. Create a demo with the scroll handler in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co

Comment: @charlietfl Well, we all have to start somewhere ;) I made a jsFiddle for your review (added at the bottom of the questions).

Comment: Hey @charlietfl, Just wanted to check back in on this question to see if you had any pointers?

Comment: demo is broken due to less dependency failing

Comment: @charlietfl sorry about that. Thanks for looking into it. New link: http://jsfiddle.net/15298c0p/

Comment: here's a suggestion, there are numerous plugins like jQuery Waypoints that would hep you out. Right now `$('.link-location').html( $(this).html() );` isn't right because `this` is the document. Also need to realize that scroll event fires many times a second so should throttle it and only make changes when thresholds are crossed

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/1697755

There's a handy function for checking element visibility:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

And to use the function might look a little something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5xgw82ft/1/

You should adjust the offsets as desired.